# Solve for $x$ and $y$ in $\left( \frac{1+i}{1-i} \right)^2+\frac{1}{x+yi}=2+5i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$ \left (\frac{1+i}{1-i} \right)^2+\frac{1}{x+y i}=2 + 5 i$

I can't figure out where to start.

Comment: Expand and set the real parts equal, and then the imaginary parts, giving you two equations in two variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Is obvious that $x,y$ they are not both zero.

Observe: $(\frac{1+i}{1-i})^{2} + \frac{1}{x+iy} = 2 + 5i$
$$\frac{1}{x+iy}=2 + 5i-((\frac{1+i}{1-i})^{2})$$
$$\frac{1}{x+iy}=2 + 5i-(-1)$$
$$\frac{1}{x+iy}=3 + 5i$$
$$\frac{x-iy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=3 + 5i$$

Then, $$\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=3$$$$\frac{-y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=5$$

So, $$\frac{x}{3}=x^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{-y}{5}$$ thus $$x=\frac{-3y}{5}$$ and replacing above is easily obtained $$y=\frac{-5}{34}, x= \frac{3}{34}$$

Comment: Why not just go from $1/(x+iy)=3+5i$ to $x+iy=1/(3+5i)=(3-5i)/(3^2+5^2)$?

Comment: True, I'm a fool. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Isolate 1/(x+yi), by subtracting the rest to the right side. Find a common denominator on the right and invert both sides. Now x+iy has been isolated and x=Re(RHS) and y=Im(RHS) (where RHS stands for right hand side).

Alternatively, instead of finding a common denominator on the right hand side you can simplify the portion with  $(1+i)/(1-i)$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{1+i}{1-i} = \frac{1+i}{1-i}\times\frac{1+i}{1+i} = \frac{(1+i)^{2}}{1-i^{2}} = \frac{2i}{2} = i\\\\
\displaystyle\frac{1}{x+yi} = \frac{1}{x+yi}\times\frac{x-yi}{x-yi} = \frac{x-yi}{x^{2}+y^{2}}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to reduce the amount of computation.
$$
{\left( {\frac{{1 + i}}{{1 - i}}} \right)^2} =  - 1
$$
$$
\frac{1}{{x + iy}} = 3 + 5i
$$
$$
\left( {3 + 5i} \right)\left( {x + iy} \right) = 1 \to \left( {3x - 5y} \right) + i\left( {5x + 3y} \right) = 1
$$
Then,

$$
\begin{cases}
3x-5y=1\\
5x+3y=0
\end{cases}
$$

and the answer will be easily obtained.